# FIO Troubleshoot Installing

Tags: software-installation

I have already installed FIO in testing and QA environments now on Production. I already simulated this error in VM separated by me. It's installed INFORMIX IBM. This is how I proceed.

Install EPEL:

```
$ rpm -iv epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

It had already installed epel-release-6-8.

```
warning: epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
```

Preparing packages for installation...

```
file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo from install of epel-release-7-11.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-6-8.noarch
file /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo from install of epel-release-7-11.noarch conflicts with file from package epel-release-6-8.noarch
```

I deleted the previous version and installed the epel-release-7. In any case when I proceed to install FIO.

```
$ gunzip fio-fio-3.7.tar.gz
$ tar -xf fio-fio-3.7.tar
```

#### When installed fio3:

```
[root@localhost fio-fio-3.7]# ./configure
configure: failed to find compiler
```

#### When installed fio-2.1.10

```
[root@localhost fio-2.1.10]# ./configure
compile test failed
Configure failed, check config.log and/or the above output
```

I thought it was the version of the EPEL, is there something I'm missing when I am installing FIO or in the `./configure`?

Answer (score 0):

(Plea: please don't use creaky old versions of fio on new systems if you have a choice. Many issues have been fixed and many things have changed between fio 2.1.10 - 3.7. See https://github.com/axboe/fio/releases for what release upstream fio is up to now)

To compile fio from source (which is what you appear to be trying to do but see the note near the bottom of this answer) you are going to need at least a compiler and several libraries. I'm not a CentOS/RHEL person usually but if memory serves when you are going to do development on CentOS/RHEL it's easier to let the system install a default set of packages by doing:

```
yum group install "Development Tools"
```

As mentioned in the fio documentation (https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#building ) you will also need to install `libaio-devel`:

```
yum install libaio-devel
```

That should then let you compile fio.

Bonus pendentry: you didn't need to install EPEL if you were going to compile fio from source. However, did you know that EPEL contains pre-built versions of fio (https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/fio ) that can be installed via `yum install fio`? Note that the version of fio in EPEL tends to be stale the older your CentOS/RHEL release is.